# SSIS XML Configuration for Connection String and Server Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, configuration, ssis

I made SSIS XML Configuration files a for the sake of simplicity I selected the option 'Reuse Existing' so multiple SSIS packages can share the same XML configuration file.  Can packages use the same config file only in the case that all packages share the same Connection Manager Name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes indeed, **as long as the package variables name are the same**, you can use the same configuration file for multiple SSIS packages.

There will be warnings if the associated configuration file contains variables that are not found in the package.